# Make view not redraw after updating ObservableObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a situation where I am using `LazyVGrid` to display Images from a users Photo library. The grid has sections, and each section contains an array of images which are to be displayed, along with some meta data about the section.

The problem I am having is that each time the user clicks on a tile, which toggles `markedForDeletion` in the corresponding Image, **all of the views in the Grid (which are visible) redraw.** This isn't ideal, as in the "real" version of the sample code there is a real penalty to redrawing each `Tile`, as images must be retrieved and rendered.

I have tried to make `Tile` conform to `Equatable`, and then use the `.equatable()` modifier to notify SwiftUI that the Tile shouldn't be redrawn, but this doesn't work.

Placing another `.onAppear` outside the `Section` hints that the entire section is being redrawn each time anything changes, but I'm not sure how to structure my code so that the impact of redrawing expensive `Tiles` is minimised.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40), spacing: 0),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40), spacing: 0),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { gr in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.imageSections.indices, id: \.self) { imageSection in
                        Section(header: Text("Section!")) {
                            ForEach(viewModel.imageSections[imageSection].images.indices, id: \.self) { imageIndex in
                                Tile(image: viewModel.imageSections[imageSection].images[imageIndex])
                                    .equatable()
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        viewModel.imageSections[imageSection].images[imageIndex].markedForDeletion.toggle()
                                    }
                                    .overlay(Color.blue.opacity(viewModel.imageSections[imageSection].images[imageIndex].markedForDeletion ? 0.2 : 0))
                                
                                    .id(UUID())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}


struct Image {
    
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var someData: String
    var markedForDeletion: Bool = false
    
}

struct ImageSection {
    
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var images: [Image]
    
    
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var imageSections: [ImageSection] = generateFakeData(numSections: 10, numImages: 10)
    
}

func generateFakeData(numSections: Int, numImages: Int) -> [ImageSection] {
    
    var sectionsToReturn: [ImageSection] = []
    
    for _ in 0 ..< numSections {
        var imageArray: [Image] = []
        
        for i in 0 ..< numImages {
            imageArray.append(Image(someData: "Data \(i)"))
        }
        
        sectionsToReturn.append(ImageSection(images: imageArray))
    }
    
    return sectionsToReturn
}

struct Tile: View, Equatable {
    
    static func == (lhs: Tile, rhs: Tile) -> Bool {
        
        return lhs.image.id == rhs.image.id
    }
    
    
    var image: Image
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(image.someData)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(Color.blue))
        
            .onAppear(perform: {
                NSLog("Appeared - \(image.id)")
            })
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Main reason of global redraw is `.id(UUID())`, because on every call it force view recreation. But to remove it and keep `ForEach` operable we need to make model identifiable explicitly.

Here is fixed parts of code. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

1. main cycle

```
ForEach(Array(viewModel.imageSections.enumerated()), id: \.1) { i, imageSection in
    Section(header: Text("Section!")) {
        ForEach(Array(imageSection.images.enumerated()), id: \.1) { j, image in
            Tile(image: image)
                .onTapGesture {
                    viewModel.imageSections[i].images[j].markedForDeletion.toggle()
                }
                .overlay(Color.red.opacity(image.markedForDeletion ? 0.2 : 0))
        }
    }
}
```

2. models (*note - your `Image` conflicts with standards SwiftUI `Image` - avoid such conflicts otherwise you might get into very unclear errors. For demo I renamed it everywhere needed to `ImageM`*)

```
struct ImageM: Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var someData: String
    var markedForDeletion: Bool = false
}

struct ImageSection: Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var images: [ImageM]
}
```